# Creating a dynamic LeaderBoard with profile pictures

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaderboard

I want to find a way to create a **leaderboard** like one below that uses **variables** to hold **Users Points** on Javascript in order to respond to changes to those points with changing users Ranks...

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Here is the picture]

I just want to **manually** fill in **User's Points Data** using only Javascript Variables... all the Data would come from a javascript array.

Something like :

```
   user_1 = Nilesh S;
   user_2 = Shristi_S; 

   user_1 points = 1710;
   user_2 points = 1710;

   etc...
```

Obviously, If I change Nilesh S (user_1) points to 1000 then Nilesh S rank will be 10th...

What I achieved for now is just creating those circle profile pictures :)

Here are the codes:

Javascript:

```
var img = document.createElement("IMG");
  img.setAttribute("src", "img_pulpit.jpg");
  img.setAttribute("width", "300");
  img.setAttribute("height", "300");
  img.setAttribute("alt", "The Pulpit Rock");
  document.body.appendChild(img);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="IMG">
<script src="Script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXm4N.png
```

CSS:

```
img {
      background: #2f293d;

   border: 1px solid #2f293d;
   padding: 6px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: .6rem .5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);

}
```

Any Solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is all the data coming from?  A database?  Are you using a server language like PHP on the backend?

Comment: No, I just inject Data using Javascript Variables or something like an array which holds those data

Comment: Totally on Javascript...

Comment: So for now you are just putting dummy data that you manually fill in with JS?

Comment: Yes...:) it's complicated to explain why I'm going to do that...

Comment: Here is a start.  This code will generate an array of 20 random numbers between 0 and 2000.  `let scores = Array.from({length: 20}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 2000));
console.log(scores);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189330/discussion-between-dmikester1-and-sara-ree).

Comment: Sara, can you answer a couple of my questions so I know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty way to create some dummy data in an objects array, sort it, and add it to the page.

```js
// this is the array that will hold all the profile objects
let profiles = [];

let profile1 = {};
profile1.name = "Jim Bob";
profile1.points = 1500;
profiles.push(profile1);

let profile2 = {};
profile2.name = "Jane Smith";
profile2.points = 1600;
profiles.push(profile2);

let profile3 = {};
profile3.name = "Mike Jones";
profile3.points = 400;
profiles.push(profile3);

let profile4 = {};
profile4.name = "Sally Peterson";
profile4.points = 1900;
profiles.push(profile4);

// sort the array by points
// b - a will make highest first, swap them so a - b to make lowest first
profiles.sort(function(a, b) { 
return b.points-a.points;
})

let profilesDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('profiles')[0];

profiles.forEach(function(entry) {
 let profile = document.createElement('div');
    profile.className = "profile";
    profile.textContent = entry.name + " -- " + entry.points;
 profilesDiv.appendChild(profile);
});
```

```css
.profile {
  border: 2px solid #222222;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="profiles">

</div>
```